# CodeIgniter 4 Route url not found "The requested URL was not found on this server." deployment on Heroku

Tags: php, codeigniter, heroku

Greetings I have a problem with my application in CodeIgniter 4, recently I moved all my websites to Heroku and for this website what is built in CodeIgniter 4 https://myconfessio.com/ only the index/home page look right but when I try to go to another page or do something else I get the error

> Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: You've removed index,php but havent properly re written your urls.  Thats why this works: https://myconfessio.com/index.php/confess.

Comment: The only thing I added is Procfile for Heroku to look in the public folder "web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/"

Comment: Everything else is by default I didn't touch anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some solution when I create .htaccess in a public folder and put this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```